# Pass Datagrid information from one SWF to another SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, datagrid, actionscript

I have two functioning scripts, one that calculates data and another that arranges a print invoice form.

I have a price breakdown datagrid in my firstFile.fla and I need the data to be passed to my secondFile.fla datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you need to pass data between two swfs on the same HTML page. This works with a [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html)

In your sender swf you need something like this:

```
var lc:LocalConnection;
lc = new LocalConnection();

function sendMyData():void
{
    lc.send("myLocalConnection", "functionToExecute", myData);
}
```

In the receiver swf:

```
var lc:LocalConnection;
lc = new LocalConnection();
lc.connect("myLocalConnection");
lc.client = this;

function functionToExecute(myData:*):void 
{
    trace("Received data " + myData);
}
```